# How to open an aspx page like a dialog in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, modal-dialog

I need to open a page like a modal dialog .I find an exemple on net but it doesn't work.

In the main page I have this code:

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
     <asp:Button Text ="Add New Course"  runat="server" ID="btnAddCourse" OnClientClick="showPanel('dialog');return false;"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            function showPanel(panelID) {
                $panel = $('#' + panelID);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/AddNew.aspx",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    async: false,
                    data: { "param": "abcd"
                    },
                    success: function (obj) {
                        // obj will contain the complete contents of the page requested
                        // use jquery to extract just the html inside the body tag
                        $content = $(obj).find('body').html();
                        // then update the dialog contents with this and show it
                        $panel.html($content);
                        $panel.dialog();
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
<div id="dialog">
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I click the button I need to open the page below .I receive an error that tell that element $ is not recognized.I don't know exactly who is element panel .Must I add a panel control ,but where ?

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddNew.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationDialog.AddNew" %>

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Add New Course </title>
 </head>
<body>
<form  >
<div id="div1">
<table>
<tr><td colspan="3"> <asp:Label ID="lblCourse" runat="server" Text="Add New Course"></asp:Label></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"> </td></tr>
<tr>
   <td style="width:40%"> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Course Name" ></asp:Label></td>
   <td style="width:20%"> </td>
   <td style="width:40%"> 
       <input id="txtName" type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="width:40%"> <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Description" ></asp:Label></td>
   <td style="width:20%"> </td>
   <td style="width:40%">
      <input id="txtDescription" type="text" />

   </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="float:right">
<input value ="Save"   id="btnSave" type="submit"  /> </td></tr>
</table>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me with this code ,to make it works ?
Thanks

Comment: This probably wont work anyway due to the fact the 'success' function is executed async, and therefore doesn't always have to know the $panel. It's best to do the panel finding in the success body

Comment: Could we also have the head section of your master page, just to see how you are referencing the libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use JQuery to load a page content into a panel but if I'm reading your code right you may not have included the JQuery library, you need to include this line of code in the `<head>` of your html code. You are also using JQueryUI dialog and will need to reference the JQueryUI library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

For Example

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<head>
```

**EDIT:** I also notice you are using the dialog, which is in JQuery UI, pleasse make sure you reference JQuery UI toolkit as well

**EDIT:** Have stripped your code into jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhPk7/1/
this seems to work for me

Comment: As TS is using master pages, I think the jQuery ref is in it's master page. Still a good remark!

Comment: Yes this is probably true, however based on the error he's getting I'd still guess that this is the issue, can't be sure without seeing the master page code

Comment: I add this reference ,I didn't have error but it doesn't do anything when I click the button :(

Comment: make sure you are referencing JQuery UI, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jquery lib reference.
At the top of a page:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"/>
```

Comment: As TS is using master pages, I think the jQuery ref is in it's master page. Still a good remark!

Comment: Whatever he is using, at the moment of his script execution jauery is not loaded.

Comment: I add this line in the head section , on the master page but it still tell me that $ is undefined

Comment: @user1577242 Can you deploy this page somewhere public?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding **jQuery script references** on your page, above the jQuery Code that you are using.

Also, add reference [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

**[Download jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)**

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery.
Change this line -> $panel = $('#' + panelID); to -> $panel = $('#div1'); and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a boolean property/setting called modal on the jQueryUI dialog, this will create a modal-type dialog.

I myself use this:

```
d.dialog({  
            autoOpen: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            closeText: '',
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: (window.document.width * 0.75),
            dialogClass: 'popup loading',
            title: 'title'),

        });
```

when you wrap this sort of function in the

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

})
```

it should popup the moment the DOM is ready..

Comment: Where should I copy this code ?And where I tell which is the page ?

Comment: In the main page or in the dialog page?

Comment: this code should be in the main page, because this page needs to open the dialog.